# Rewrite url not work

Tags: url-rewriting

I try made my url friendly:

`https://xxxxx.com/imovel?apartamento-cangaíba-são+paulo-73+m²`

to

`https://xxxxx.com/imovel/apartamento-cangaíba-são+paulo-73+m²`

Need change `?` to `/`

My apache ssl file configuration is:

```
RewriteEngine On

                RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
                RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^33\.333\.33\.33$
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xxxxx.com [L,R=301]


                # To remove trailing slash
#               RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#               RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

                # To remove .php extension
                RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

                # To check whether the file exists then set it back internally
                RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
                RewriteRule ^.*$ $0.php [L]

                #Seo imovel
                RewriteRule ^imovel/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /imovel?titulo=$1 [NC]
```

I only need now change the `?` to `/`.

In my action form:

```
<form id="f_det" method="post" action="imovel?<?php echo strtolower(urlencode($imovels->tipo_imob."-".$imovels->bairro_imob."-".$imovels->cidade_imob."-".$tam_m2));?>">
```

Cant find my mistake. Dont work on the end url is like:

`https://xxxxx.com/imovel?apartamento-cangaíba-são+paulo-73+m²`

Answer (score 0):

Please change your action url imovel? to imovel/, like below,

```
<form id="f_det" method="post" action="imovel/<?php echo strtolower(urlencode($imovels->tipo_imob."-".$imovels->bairro_imob."-".$imovels->cidade_imob."-".$tam_m2));?>">
```

Comment: Tks, for atention, when i try that, the server response is not found... I dont know if others rules make that...